# Cómo actualizar una columna a partir de una diferencia de sumatorias?

Tags: sql, ms-access

tengo la siguiente tabla en Access:

```
ID  |   Name  |  Dog    |   Cat   |
===================================
1   | A       |   100   |   0     |
1   | B       |   0     |   100   |
1   | C       |   50    |   0     |
2   | A       |   100   |   0     |
2   | B       |   3     |   100   |
2   | C       |   3     |   50    |
```

Mediante una consulta la necesito así:

```
ID  |   Name  |  Dog    |   Cat   |
===================================
1   | A       |   100   |   0     |
1   | B       |   0     |   100   |
1   | C       |   50    |   0     |
1   | TOTAL   |   50    |   0     |
2   | A       |   100   |   0     |
2   | B       |   0     |   100   |
2   | C       |   0     |   50    |
2   | TOTAL   |   0     |   -50   |
```

Como pueden ver, sumo el total de la columna Dog y Cat donde el registro ID sea igual, después sumo esos totales de la siguiente manera Dog - Cat, si ese valor es positivo va a la columna Dog, si es negativo a la columna Cat. La verdad soy novato en esto y he visto preguntas similares, pero realmente quiero saber cual es la opción más sencilla de manejar esto. Gracias.

Lo que llevo es así:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Dog, Cat
FROM Tabla
UNION 
SELECT ID, 'Total', SUM(Dog), SUM(Cat)
FROM Tabla
GROUP BY ID
```

Y me da el resultado siguiente:

```
ID  |   Name  |  Sum(Dog)|   Sum(Cat)|
======================================
1   | A       |   100    |   0       |
1   | B       |   0      |   100     |
1   | C       |   50     |   0       |
1   | TOTAL   |   150    |   100     |
2   | A       |   100    |   0       |
2   | B       |   0      |   100     |
2   | C       |   0      |   50      |
2   | TOTAL   |   100    |   150     |
```

Ahora lo que me haría falta es restar el total de sumatoria de Dog con Cat y ese resultado ponerlo en otra fila, sí es positivo ese resultado a la columna Dog y si es negativo a la columna Cat.

Comment: Para que podamos ayudarte, edita la pregunta y añade el código que has intentado. Así podremos ver que tienes y ayudarte donde estés atascado

Comment: Esto es lo que se me ha ocurrido, pero veo que no es legítimo.INSERT INTO Tabla (Name, Dog, Cat)
VALUES ('Total', SUM(Dog), SUM(Cat))

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esa tabla que estas mostrando no es una tabla valida para SQL. porque queres algo asi? los problemas de vista los debe solucionar la vista

Comment: Insert inserta un registro en una tabla.. Porque querrias hacer algo asi?

Comment: Entiendo, claro lo que necesito no es nueva información.

Comment: y entonces, que queres hacer? esa consulta no es logica, y aunque se pueda hacer que salga algo asi, para una db va a ser muy pero muy costoso. porque queres algo asi en una db?

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu campo clave principal en ambas tablas? Porque veo que se repite el ID. ¿No tienes un campo clave que identifique a cada registro de manera única? Aun así, probablemente tengas que hacer una consulta UNION ALL para ir creándote un conjunto de registros adaptado a tus necesidades, ya que parece que siempre tienes el mismo número de columnas. Respecto a tus datos, por favor, explica mejor eso de *sumo el total de la columna Dog y Cat, después sumo Dog - Cat*, por favor.

Comment: No tendría campo con registros únicos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a ver si esto te sirve. ME he importado tus datos de ejemplo a una tabla en Access, sin clave principal. Luego, con una consulta UNION ALL he construido una query que muestra lo que tú quieres, aunque con algunos cambios que te muestro en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ves, los campos se llaman como tú pides es decir, `ID, Name, Dog, Cat`. Y muestra los valores de origen que tú pusiste:

```
ID  |   Name  |  Dog    |   Cat   |
===================================
1   | A       |   100   |   0     |
1   | B       |   0     |   100   |
1   | C       |   50    |   0     |
2   | A       |   100   |   0     |
2   | B       |   0     |   100   |
2   | C       |   0     |   50    |
```

yo he creado una fila que en `Name` pone `SUMATORIOS DOG Y CAT`. Esta fila es el sumatorio de los campos `Dog` y `Cat` respectivamente.

Luego, he añadido otra fila que se llama `TOTAL DOG-CAT`. En esta fila, al sumatorio de `DOG` le resta el sumatorio de `CAT`. Si es 0 o positivo, lo muestra en la columna `DOG` y en la de `CAT` muestra un 0. Si es negativo, entonces en la columna`DOG` muestra un 0 y en la columna `CAT` muestra el resultado.

Para esta query, he usado la siguiente estructura:

```
SELECT Tabla.ID, Tabla.Name, Tabla.Dog, Tabla.Cat
FROM Tabla
UNION ALL SELECT Tabla.ID, "SUMATORIOS DOG Y CAT" AS Expr1, Sum(Tabla.Dog) AS SumaDeDog, Sum(Tabla.Cat) AS SumaDeCat
FROM Tabla
GROUP BY Tabla.ID, "SUMATORIOS DOG Y CAT"
UNION ALL
SELECT Tabla.ID, "TOTAL DOG-CAT" AS Expr1, Sum(0) AS Expr2, Sum([DOG]-[CAT]) AS NEGATIVOS
FROM Tabla
GROUP BY Tabla.ID, "TOTAL DOG-CAT"
HAVING (((Sum([DOG]-[CAT]))<0))
UNION ALL SELECT Tabla.ID, "TOTAL DOG-CAT" AS Expr1, Sum([DOG]-[CAT]) AS POSITIVOS, Sum(0) AS Expr2
FROM Tabla
GROUP BY Tabla.ID, "TOTAL DOG-CAT"
HAVING (((Sum([DOG]-[CAT]))>=0))
ORDER BY Tabla.ID, Tabla.Name;
```

No es exactamente igual que lo tuyo (tú usas la palabra TOTAL por ejemplo), pero a mí hacerlo de esta manera me ha servido, y de hecho, obtengo todos los valores que pides en tu pregunta.

Espero que pueda servirte para llegar a tu meta, y que puedas adaptar la sentencia SQL a tus necesidades :)

A mí tener columna `Name` no me ha dado problemas, la verdad.

Comment: Gracias, es totalmente funcional, como tal no genera error al usar la palabra `Name` , pero sí sugiere no usar esa palabra, mejor dicho no es recomendado.

Answer (score 1):

Usar nombres como Value o Name para una columna genera problemas.

```
SELECT ID, Nama, SUM(Dog), Sum(Cat)
FROM Tabla
GROUP BY ID, Nama

UNION 

SELECT ID, "Total", SUM(Dog), Sum(Cat)
FROM Tabla
GROUP BY ID

UNION

SELECT ID, "Total 2", IIF(SUM(Dog) - Sum(Cat) >= 0, SUM(Dog) - Sum(Cat), "" ), IIF(SUM(Dog) - Sum(Cat) <= 0, SUM(Dog) - Sum(Cat), "" )
FROM Tabla
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: tengo duda el IF que pones debe ir con doble II?

Comment: Sí, así lo maneja Access, recibe tres parámetros, la expresión a evaluar, sí es verdadera y si es falsa. https://support.office.com/es-es/article/función-silnm-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3?omkt=es-CO&ui=es-ES&rs=es-CO&ad=CO